# retrieve hidden text value using javascript function comes object HTMLinputElement error

Tags: javascript, html

hidden text value is 1

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="intwstatus" name="status">
```

I use this function to retrieve the value.

```
 <script>
        function adddetails()
        {
        var intwstaus= $('#intwstatus').val();
        alert(intwstatus);
        }
    </script>
```

The value of the variable intwstatus is 1 but alert box shows the error object HTMLinputElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple error.. variable names are different.. This will work

```
 var intwstatus= $('#intwstatus').val();
        alert(intwstatus);
```

Answer (score 4):

Its simply a typo in your code.
Change `var intwstaus` to `var intwstatus`

Interestingly, looks like input ids in html result in "predeclared" variable names. Your `id="intwstatus"` input, results in a window scope `intwstatus` reference to the dom input element

```js
alert(someInput);
alert(myOtherInput.id);
alert(intwstatus.name);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="intwstatus" name="status">
<input id="someInput" value="3">
<input id="myOtherInput">
```